# Nautilus uses different permissions for mounted drives

Tags: nautilus, mount, permissions, automount, udisks

I've written two bash scripts to give read-only or read/write access to my NTFS partition:

read-only access:

```
sudo umount /media/Data_Drive/  
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro,user,auto,nls=utf8,umask=0000,uid=1000 /dev/sda2 /media/Data_Drive
```

read/write access:

```
sudo umount /media/Data_Drive/  
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw,user,auto,nls=utf8,umask=0000,uid=1000 /dev/sda2 /media/Data_Drive
```

It works perfectly if I only use terminal to work with the files. It also works with Nautilus in read-only mode but not in the read/write mode. In fact, Nautilus gives me an error when I try to copy a file to Data_Drive saying "The destination is read-only".

More funny, when I look at the permissions (by right-clicking on Data_Drive and then properties->permissions) I have all the required permissions to write a file in Data_Drive!

I am so confused why Nautilus behaves strangely. I appreciate if anybody could solve the mystery!

Answer (score 9):

It's a bug: Nautilus says the USB stick is read only when it is not  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375

Comment: While that bug isn't listed as fixed, I came across the issue today with a new disk, did an `apt-get dist-upgrade` and the new version seemed to have the fix in.  OP, this should probably be marked as a correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

This Bug can fixed by:

- Removing /home/[my-username]/.config/nautilus directory and after logout and new login the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;dr:**

> Run `killall nautilus` and remount.

---

As mentioned by [@Luis Medina](https://askubuntu.com/a/205853/289003), this is a bug in Nautilus: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375.

I'm unclear whether it was fixed at one point, but I still experience it in 16.04, and users on the bug's thread are facing it in 16.10.

As a workaround, unmount the partition and run `killall nautilus`. Remount and the problem should be solved. This was suggested by users on the bug's thread, and it's worked for me as well.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Can someone explain their downvote? This solution worked perfectly for me (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)