# USB read-only via graphic UI and writable via CLI

Tags: command-line, usb, nautilus, filesystem, read-only

Why I'm unable to write on USB via Files (Nautilus, graphic UI) and I'm able to write on it using CLI?

Using Files I'm getting the error: `Error while copying to "DEVICENAME". This destination is read-only.`

Using CLI I'm able to create new files, copy content and so on.

Here is the output of `mount` for the related device:

```
/dev/sdb2 on /media/USERNAME/DEVICENAME type fat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1815567,gid=333,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

I don't have root permission.

Comment: Are you doing both as the same user? Is it properly mounted?

Comment: Same user. What do you mean about properly mounted?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -a /media/USERNAME`?

Comment: Output of: `ls -a /media/USERNAME` is: `.    ..    MG-4`

Comment: Can you open `MG-4` in Nautilus and write? Check its permissions in Nautilus.

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R USERNAME /media/USERNAME/MG-4`

Comment: I can open `MG-4` in Nautilus but I'm unable to write on it. I can't use `sudo`, I don't have root permission.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37052/discussion-between-bharadwaj-raju-and-matteo-guarnerio).

Comment: Maybe this is related: http://askubuntu.com/q/156518/380067